# Randomly select rows in HIVE, half of which must satisfy a condition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Right now I have:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table1
   DISTRIBUTE BY rand()
   SORT BY rand()
   limit 2;
```

But I need to add a qualifying statement so that half of the randomly retrieved rows satisfy a specified condition:

```
WHERE count(id) > 3
GROUP BY name;
```

while the other half of the rows do NOT satisfy this condition. However, I can't have one subset more overrepresented than the other i.e. those who have a count(id) > 3 should be the same amount as those <3. I thought of using a union, but think that's not possible as the queries will be querying the same table. How do I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select
*
from(
select
Src_sys_id
From fin.table
where src_sys_id = "123"
limit 10
union all
select src_sys_id
From fin.table
where src_sys_id <> "123"
limit 10) a;
```

You can add any additional clauses to the select statements if you'd like. Just ensure that each select statement returns the same # of columns for the union to work.

Comment: The question states "***Randomly*** select rows in Hive".  If I run this query more than once will I get different values each time?